# My UL is not responsive when placed in a TD

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have a jquery slider called pgwslidemaster. The slideshow is fully responsive on its own.
When I place it within my td of a table, it become unresponsive.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="background-color:#e9e9e9; border-top-color:#FFF; border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:1px;">

   <center><div style="margin-top:10px; width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;">
   <ul class="pgwSlideshow">


   <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/san-francisco.jpg" alt="San Francisco, USA" data-description="Golden Gate Bridge"></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/rio.jpg" alt="Rio de Janeiro, Brazil"></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/london.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/new-york.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/new-delhi.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/paris.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/sydney.jpg" alt=""></li>



</ul>
</div></center></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="PgwSlideshow-master/pgwslideshow.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pgwSlideshow = $('.pgwSlideshow').pgwSlideshow();
    pgwSlideshow.stopSlide();

});
</script>
```

when I put it into my td's it suddenly becomes not responsive:

```
<tr style="display:table-row">
    <td height="80" style="display:table-cell"><div id="wrapper-bottom"><span style="font-size:15px;"><img src="images/icon-info.png" width="29" height="29" align="left" style="margin-right:15px; margin-bottom: 15px;"/><span style="text-transform:uppercase; color: #E73227; font-weight: 700; font-size: 25px;">Property Name</span><br />
    Location: <span style="color:#666">Place</span></span></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" style="" ><div style="background-color:#e9e9e9; border-top-color:#FFF; border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:1px;">

   <center><div style="margin-top:10px; width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;">
   <ul class="pgwSlideshow">


   <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/san-francisco.jpg" alt="San Francisco, USA" data-description="Golden Gate Bridge"></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/rio.jpg" alt="Rio de Janeiro, Brazil"></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/london.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/new-york.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/new-delhi.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/paris.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="PgwSlideshow-master/sydney.jpg" alt=""></li>



</ul>
</div></center></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="PgwSlideshow-master/pgwslideshow.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pgwSlideshow = $('.pgwSlideshow').pgwSlideshow();
    pgwSlideshow.stopSlide();

});
</script>
</td>
  </tr>
```

Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: is all the table styling being applied in the html or do you have any external stylesheets (much better btw)

Comment: I do have it in the css as well. table {
display: table; 
}
td{
 display:table-cell;
}

Comment: When I remove it from the html, it does not make a difference.

Comment: What you you mean by "responsive" exactly? If you're concerned that the div in the first example is full width, but the table in the second is only as wide as its content, that is normal behaviour. Divs and tables do behave differently.

Comment: I mean that it does not resize to size of page. If I make the page smaller it will not proportionately adjust. Anyway to have it work to resize both ways?

Comment: Yes, adding `width:100%` to the styles for a table makes it as wide as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the table elements and replaced them with divs. That fully solved my problem and the page now resizes for every element.